# How to save using get and set in android studio java

Tags: java, android-studio, get, set

I'm making a text adventure and I was wondering how would I save the players position using get and set with the buttons being in another activity, so far I have this:

```
public class Player
{
    private int playerPos;
    private String inventory;


    Player()
    {
        playerPos = 0;
        inventory = "NOTHING";
    }

    Player(int newPosition)
    {
        playerPos = newPosition;
        inventory = "NOTHING";
    }

    public int getPlayerPos() { return playerPos; }

    public String getInventory() { return inventory; }

    public void setPlayerPos(int playerPos) { this.playerPos = playerPos; }

    public void setInventory(String inventory) { this.inventory = inventory; }

}   //  public class Player
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the playerPos attribute static , then from another activity when you change it with setter it will be saved , and you can always get the saved position with getter

Comment: Hey, I'm relatively new to Java so sorry for any annoying questions, but make it `private static int playerPos`? Then from the other activity with a save/load button how would I make it set and get? In the save button for example would I do
`Player save;
 save = new Player();
 save.setPlayerPos();`
perhaps?

Comment: Yes exactly , its not annoying everyone had his first time , you're right about what you said but when you set the player's position you have to fill in the new position you want to save : save.setPlayerPos( your_new_pos ) , **NB : this will help you if you wanna create one player only , else it will have another mecanism bcs the edited position will update to all playes**

Comment: How would the new position work? So far there are 3 rooms being 0, 1 and 2, so do I just put 0 as the position? And for inventory `save.setInventory("nothing");` would that work? There's only 1 item at the moment would it record that item? Thanks

Comment: @Diedis yes that's how to use setter , for inventory it will work bcs its a String so yea

Comment: Welcome @Diedis